# How to get the name of an Oid ? (SnmpSharpNet lib)

Tags: c#, snmp

How to get the name of an Oid ?

I followed [examples in the site](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/node/9) but I did not found how to do this. To retrieve MIB strings, there is no problem (example from the site) :

```
// Walk through returned variable bindings
foreach (Vb v in result.Pdu.VbList)
{
    // Check that retrieved Oid is "child" of the root OID
    if (rootOid.IsRootOf(v.Oid))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}): {2}",
            v.Oid.ToString(),
            SnmpConstants.GetTypeName(v.Value.Type),

            v.Value.ToString());
        if (v.Value.Type == SnmpConstants.SMI_ENDOFMIBVIEW)
            lastOid = null;
        else
            lastOid = v.Oid;
    }
    else
    {
        // we have reached the end of the requested
        // MIB tree. Set lastOid to null and exit loop
        lastOid = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "name" of an Oid. Oid's are a numbering scheme that can be (carefully) extended by any organisation that choose to do so. As such, there's no central registry of Oids, and I'd expect an application working with them to already have the names of the Oids they're interested in working with.

Comment: name like "interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifDescr"

Answer (score 1):

**You are warned that I am the main developer of #SNMP**

To get names of OIDs, you need the corresponding MIB documents. However, I don't think SNMP#NET currently has this feature to load the MIB documents and allows you to do translation.

#SNMP has this feature for a relatively long time, and its snmptranslate sample shows how to achieve this,

http://pro.sharpsnmp.com

Comment: Thank you to answer me :-) I have already tested #SNMP but you convince me to retest it ;-)

Comment: @Lex Li: It would be nice if you state your affiliation with #SNMP.

Comment: @Isaac acknowledged.